# Passing unknown size std::Array in a function with template. How can I correct this code?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I wrote this code using 2d Vector and Array. But I wanted to use `std::array` this time and my code did not work because this was the first time I use `std::array` and template.

It gave me for this line:

> `array<array<int, sizeY>, sizeX> arr;`

this error:

> Error C2971   `std::array`: template parameter `_Size`: `sizeY,sizeX`: a variable with non-static storage duration cannot be used as a non-type argument

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

template <size_t Y, size_t X>
bool IsMagicSquare(array<array<int, Y>, X>& ar)
{
    int x = ar.size();
    int y = ar[0].size();

    if (x == y)
    {
        int ver[x] = {  };
        int hor[y] = {  };
        int cross0 = 0;
        int cross1 = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                hor[i] += ar[i][j];
                ver[j] += ar[i][j];
                if (i == j)
                    cross0 += ar[i][j];
                if (i + j == x - 1)
                    cross1 += ar[i][j];
            }
        }
        if (cross0 != cross1)
            return false;
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                if ((cross0 != ver[i]) || (cross1 != hor[i]))
                    return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return false;

    return true;
}
int main()
{
    int sizeX, sizeY;
    cout << "Size of Matrix:";
    cin >> sizeX >> sizeY;

  **array<array<int, sizeY>, sizeX> arr;**

    cout << "Elements of the Matrix:";
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++)
            cin >> arr[i][j];

    if (IsMagicSquare(arr))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeX; i++)
        {
            cout << "\n";
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeY; j++)
                cout << arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Matrix is not magical square!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as sizes are runtime.

Comment: Similar problem inside `IsMagicSquare()`: C-style arrays with run-time known size (`int ver[x] = {  }; int hor[y] = {  };`) isn't C++; maybe is supported, as extension, from some compilers, but isn't standard C++

Comment: I was trying to create x and y lenght zeros.

Comment: @EmRul in `IsMagicSquare`, you can simply replace `x` and `y` with `X` and `Y`, respectively. But in `main`, there is simply no way to instantiate `arr` using the `sizeX` and `sizeY` variables since their values are not known at compile time.

Comment: You can try `std::vector<int> ver(x, 0), hor(y,0);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wrote this code using 2d Vector and Array.

That is appropriate, as you do not know the size of the matrix until run time.

> But I wanted to use `std::array` this time [...]

Well, that's a problem because the size of a `std::array` must be known at compile time. Moving away from C-style arrays is a recommended move, but you have to know where to go. Use the correct tool for the job at hand.

**Fixed-size arrays:** For arrays whose size is known by the compiler, a `std::array` is a reasonable replacement. In fact, the `std::array` is probably nothing more than the C-style array with a different interface.

**Variable-size arrays:** For arrays whose size is not known until run time, a `std::vector` is a reasonable replacement. Even though the name does not say "array", it is an array. It is a bit more complex than `std::array`, but that is because it supports sizes not known at compile time.

This distinction tends to be better-known by those not using gcc, as that compiler has an extension that supports declaring variable-size C-style arrays using the same syntax as declaring fixed-size C-style arrays. It is standard C++ to declare an array along the lines of `int col[10]`. However, it is not standard C++ to declare an array along the lines of `int col[sizeY]`,  where `sizeY` has a value supplied at run time. The latter syntax is supported by gcc as an extension, and some people use it without realizing it is an extension (ported from gcc's C support). To some extent, `std::vector` makes this extension available in a more portable form.

Answer (score 3):

The size of an array (or template arguments in general) has to be known at compile-time, so there is no way to use the runtime values `sizeX`, `sizeY` as size (template argument) for an array.

You have to use a variable-length container like `std::vector` instead.

Comment: As I sad in my question, I did already and it's worked. I am trying to understand std:: array better. So I am looking for a std::array solution

Comment: For more correctness: the size of an array does not need to be known at compile time if the array has dynamic storage. `std::array` can never have a runtime size though, because template arguments must be known at compile time.

Comment: @EmRul there is no solution, because `std::array` is a fixed-length array whose size MUST be known at compile time, so you CAN'T use variables whose values are not known until runtime. This is exactly what `std::vector` is good for instead

Comment: @EmRul you can't. As I said the value of `sizeY`, `sizeX`  is not known at compile-time and as of that cannot be used as template argument (size of the array). If you know that the `sizeY`, and `sizeX` are in a certain range (e.g. `1-9`) then you could do something like `if( sizeY==1 && sizeX==1 ) { array<array<int, 1>, 1> … } else if( sizeY==2 && sizeX==1 ) { array<array<int, 2>, 1> … } `, for all possible combinations. Forcing the compiler to create a specialization of `IsMagicSquare` for each of those arrays.

Comment: @eerorika what exactly do you mean with `if the array has dynamic storage`?

Comment: Ok thanks, I understood. So std::array isn't better than c array.

Comment: @t.niese There are four storage classes: Automatic, static, thread local and dynamic. Objects created with a new-expression have dynamic storage.

Comment: @EmRul An `std::array` is better than using a `c` style array. In c++ `c` style arrays also don't have a variable-length (compilers might support it, but it's not part of the standard). The handling of `std::array`s is easier, e.g. because `std::array` their size with the type.

Comment: @eerorika But normally you use the `std::array` you created dynamically with `new` in some way. And for the code that has to be generate by the compiler when using an `std::array` no matter how it was created, the compiler needs to know the template argument (size)  to create the code for that size accordingly, and also for memory layout e.g. if a temporary copy of that array is created on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here's how you can get a `std::array` with a size which is decided at runtime:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct DynArray {
    virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual T * data() = 0;
    virtual ~DynArray() {}
};
template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct DynArrayImpl : public DynArray<T> {
    std::array<T, Size> array;
    std::size_t size() const override {
        return array.size();
    }
    T * data() override {
        return array.data();
    }
};

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct DynArrayFactory {
    static DynArray<T> * allocate(std::size_t const size) {
        if (size > Size) {
            // ERROR
            return nullptr;
        }
        if (size == Size) {
            return new DynArrayImpl<T, Size>();
        }
        return DynArrayFactory<T, Size - 1>::allocate(size);
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct DynArrayFactory<T, 0> {
    static DynArray<T> * allocate(std::size_t const size) {
        if (size > 0) {
            return nullptr;
        }
        return new DynArrayImpl<T, 0>();
    }
};


int main() {
    std::size_t size;
    std::cin >> size;
    std::unique_ptr<DynArray<int>> array{DynArrayFactory<int, 100>::allocate(size)};
    std::cout << array->size() << std::endl;
}
```

This requires a maximum size (100 in this case) to be specified at compile time and is a really convoluted way of doing things; **thus not recommended**.

Accessing the `std::array` is nearly impossible though, unless with similar templated code which then generates code for each possible size (see below).  This will generate *a lot* of code.  One can easily access the contents of the array however, as seen in the example above. But really: use `std::vector`.

---

"similar templated code":

```cpp
template<std::size_t Size>
struct FillWithNumbers {
    static void run(std::array<int, Size> & array) {
        int n = 0;
        std::generate(begin(array), end(array), [&n](){ return n++; });
    }
};

template<typename T, std::size_t Size>
struct DynArrayApply {
    template<template<std::size_t S> class Fn>
    static void apply(DynArray<T> & array) {
        if (array.size() > Size) {
            // ERROR
        }
        if (array.size() == Size) {
            DynArrayImpl<T, Size> & real = dynamic_cast<DynArrayImpl<T, Size> &>(array);
            Fn<Size>::run(real.array);
        }
        else {
            DynArrayApply<T, Size - 1>::template apply<Fn>(array);
        }
    }
};
template<typename T>
struct DynArrayApply<T,0> {
    template<template<std::size_t S> class Fn>
    static void apply(DynArray<T> & array) {
        if (array.size() > 0) {
            // ERROR
        }
        DynArrayImpl<T, 0> & real = dynamic_cast<DynArrayImpl<T, 0> &>(array);
        Fn<0>::run(real.array);
    }
};


int main() {
    std::size_t size;
    std::cin >> size;
    std::unique_ptr<DynArray<int>> array{DynArrayFactory<int, 100>::allocate(size)};
    DynArrayApply<int, 100>::apply<FillWithNumbers>(*array);
    std::cout << array->size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << array->data()[array->size() / 2] << std::endl;
}
```